# Find common elements from two very large Arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are two integer arrays ,each in very large files (size of each is larger than RAM). How would you find the common elements in the arrays in linear time.

I cant find a decent solution to this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: are they sorted?

Comment: are the values in the files written in binary ?

Comment: normal 4 byte integers lets assume.. thats all the question is.

Comment: It makes a lot of difference though - if they were 16 bit ints there would be a pretty trivial solution.

Comment: @harold: I don't think I follow you. What is so special about number 16?

Comment: @Groo: 2^16 is small enough to make counting sort feasible.

Comment: aah.. count sort on 16 bits makes me itch.. I shouldve said that. :P

Comment: @Fanael: that's correct, I had a bitarray in mind to store the presence flags only, but now that I've done the calculation it's nevertheless pretty big (4096Mb/8=512Mb). Right now all I can think of is a disk-based hash table if O(n) is needed.

Comment: yes. i was thinking of a bitarray as flags as well, and i think 512 MB isnt thaaaat much . Its a decent solution , and will be fast as its all in the ram. lets see what others have to say.

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee: that's basically what [AProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8973659/69809) wrote below. That would be a "bitmap" (s)he mentioned.

Comment: @Groo it might not be _quite_ as fast as you think, since it sets records for playing poorly with the cache.  However, it still beats touching the disk.

Comment: @Groo, on my 32G machine, half a gig doesn't seem big ;-). BTW, as an interviewer, when I ask those kind of questions, I'm more interested in the presentation of alternatives and the trade-off analysis made than in a single answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One pass on one file build a bitmap (or a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) if the integer range is too large for a bitmap in memory).

One pass on the other file find the duplicates (or candidates if using a Bloom filter).

If you use a Bloom filter, the result is probabilistic. New passes can reduce the false positive (Bloom filters don't have false negative).

Comment: For 4 bytes integers, you don't need a Bloom filter, just 0.5Gbytes of memory.

Comment: thats dooable i guess, . sounds like a nice solution . thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming integer size is 4 bytes.
Now we can have maximum of 2^32 integers i.e I can have a bitvector of 2^32 bits (512 MB) to represent all integers where each bit reperesents 1 integer.
1. Initialize this vector with all zeroes
2. Now go through one file and set bits in this vector to 1 if you find an integer.
3. Now go through other file and look for any set bit in bit Vector.

Time complexity O(n+m)
space complexity 512 MB

Comment: That would work only if multiple occurrences can be treatened like a single output. Great in my opinion.

Comment: 2^32 bits is 512Mb, isn't it?

Comment: This is almost the same as the above solution'

Comment: @blaze, 2^32 is 512Mbits i.e 64 MBytes

Comment: @Kshitij, you dont have to learn about bloom filters with this solution :)

Comment: @Manan 2^32 bits = 4294967296 bits = 536870912 bytes = 512 * 1024 * 1024 = 512 Mbytes. Isn't it good that 32-bit systems can address 4Gb of memory, not 512Mb?

Answer (score 4):

You can obviously use an hash table to find common elements with O(n) time complexity.

First, you need to create an hash table using the first array, then compare the second array using this hash table.

Comment: The size of the list is GREATER than the RAM.. your hashtable will not hold any array completely.. :/

Comment: please elaborate... what you mean

Comment: A file-based hash table is just a hash table where the table is stored in a file instead of in memory.

Comment: ok.. if the hashtable is in a file. it will work. But doesnt sound like a very efficient way.

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee But it is O(n), and deterministic - unlike the Bloom Filter method.

Comment: Assuming you have a memory greater than the RAM, and very large does not refer infinity: it is not the only way but one of the most efficient way to do.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say enough RAM is available to hold 5% of hash of either given file-array (FA).

So, I can split the file arrays (FA1 and FA2) into 20 chunks each - say do a MOD 20 of the contents. We get FA1(0)....FA1(19) and FA2(0)......FA2(19). This can be done in linear time.

Hash FA1(0) in memory and compare contents of FA2(0) with this hash. Hashing and checking for existence are constant time operations.

Destroy this hash and repeat for FA1(1)...FA1(19). This is also linear. So, the whole operation is linear.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are talking of integers with the same size, and written in the files in binary mode, you first sort the 2 files (use a quicksort, but reading and writing to the file "offsets" ).
Then you just need to move from the start of the 2 files, and check for matches, if you have a match write the output to another file (assuming you can't also store the result in memory) and keep moving on the files until EOF.

Comment: Sorting isn't O(n) as required.

Comment: Sorting fixed-size integers is actually O(n): radix sort. But handling files larger then memory can be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Sort files. With fixed length integers it can be done in O(n) time:

1. Get some part of file, sort it with radix sort, write to temporary file. Repeat until all data finished. This part is O(n)
2. Merge sorted parts. This is O(n) too. You can even skip repeated numbers.

On sorted files find a common subset of integers: compare numbers, write it down if they are equal, then step one number ahead on file with smaller number. This is O(n).

All operations are O(n) and final algorithm is O(n) too.

EDIT: bitmap method is much faster if you have enough memory for bitmaps. This method works for any fixed size integers, 64-bit for example. Bitmap of size 2^31 Mb will not be practical for at least a few years :)